# Sending Remote AT commands to Remote Xbee using python-xbee

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, xbee

I have connected coordinator xbee to serial port of beaglebone i.e . tx and rx of beaglebone. My router's D0 pin is connected to relay. I want to remotely disable or enable the D0 pin. For that i am using python-xbee library. What I did is (my python code snippet)

```js
myRouter='\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xE4\x29\xB3'
#For Off
xbee.remote_at(dest_addr_long=myRouter,command='D0',parameter='\x04')
#For switch ON
xbee.remote_at(dest_addr_long=myRouter,command='D0',parameter='\x05')
```

code is working fine without error but I am not getting the output.
I tried it using without beaglebone i.e. using usb explorer it works. Here is the [link of example @ digi](http://www.digi.com/blog/community/xbee-broadcast-tech-tip-using-remote-at-commands-to-toggle-an-io/).

I am using [python-xbee library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XBee). What would be the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python-xbee library, "frame-id" for remote_at is '0x0' by default. you will not receive the response if id is 0.

http://www.digi.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/techtip10.png .

Frame Id is 01, in XCTU. You need to change "id" to anything other than zero to receive the response.

Comment: Thanks. I'll Try and let you know